# Installing snort on Amazon Linux Dependancy Issue (libpcre.so.1)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, snort

I am trying to install snort on an amazon virtual machine, and I am running into a dependency issue. I would really appreciate any help! :D

Operating system info below:

```
# uname -a

Linux hostname 4.1.13-19.30.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 11 03:42:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have downloaded the snort rpm, (the centos version as that is what amazon linux is based on, I have also tried directly with yum, and I have encountered the same issue).  Evidence below:

```
# yum localinstall snort-2.9.8.0-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Examining snort-2.9.8.0-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm: 1:snort-2.9.8.0-1.x86_64
Marking snort-2.9.8.0-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package snort.x86_64 1:2.9.8.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdnet.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:snort-2.9.8.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:snort-2.9.8.0-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:snort-2.9.8.0-1.x86_64 (/snort-2.9.8.0-1.centos7.x86_64)
       Requires: libdnet.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:snort-2.9.8.0-1.x86_64 (/snort-2.9.8.0-1.centos7.x86_64)
       Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I check the depencdancy with yum, evidence below:

```
# yum provides libdnet
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
libdnet-1.11-1.1.el3.rf.x86_64 : Simple portable interface to lowlevel networking routines
Repo        : installed
```

Could the issue be related to a symbolic link?

Or could it be an operating system incompatibility issue?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! :D

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get libdnet? It looks like its from RPM forge(rf) and possibly an older version(el3).

Comment: I attempted to install this. I did manage to get the libdnet depedency installed with `sudo yum install libdnet --enablerepo=epel`. I did run into problems with the other dependency though.

Comment: @datasage  First of all thanks for replying, I ran your code, and it did install an updated version of libnet :)

Dependency Updated:
libdnet-devel.x86_64 0:1.12-6.el6

However I get the same message when I try to install snort :(  Which version of snort did you install?  Maybe I should start with a different version? :)

Comment: I tried to install the newest 2.9.x version. Once I installed `libdnet` the dependency message for that file went away. I wasn't able to figure out the libpcre one though.

Comment: As I am using ec2, it might just be easier to move my data to a ubuntu box and install snort there :(

Comment: That is also an option, or you could also find an base image of Centos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This finally fixed the libdnet error for me:

```
sudo yum install libdnet-devel.x86_64 --enablerepo=epel
```

I also had to install these through yum to get Snort and DAQ to configure and make properly:

- bison.x86_64
- flex.x86_64
- libpcap.x86_64
- pcre-devel.x86_64

Those four didn't require the EPEL (extended package) repo from yum.